# Typo3: t3lib_userAuth::getRawUserByUid: Using $this when not in object context

Tags: typo3

I'm trying to retrieve a particular user's data in Typo3 using the t3lib_userAuth class. Specifically I'm doing this:

```
$user = t3lib_userAuth::getRawUserByUid ($uid);
```

and I'm getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in /var/www/html/test/typo3_477/t3lib/class.t3lib_userauth.php on line 1384
```

which makes sense since I didn't instantiate the class. However, t3lib_userAuth does not have a constructor method, so I'm at a loss how to correctly instantiate it.

Does anybody know how to correctly setup/init this class or how to retrieve an already configured one using the Typo3 API?

Greetings/Thanks
Robert

Answer (score 0):

Actually `t3lib_userAuth` is an abstract class, which means you will probably have to instantiate either a `t3lib_beUserAuth` or `t3lib_feUserAuth` class (look at the inheritance diagram e.g. on http://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/45/html/classt3lib__user_auth.html).

Normally in most TYPO3 contexts you already have one of those lying around - e.g. `$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user`, otherwise you could use the `t3lib_div::makeInstance()` method to get one.